# How to assign unique values to groups of rows in a pandas dataframe based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
example = [{'A':3}, {'A':5}, {'A':0}, {'A':2}, {'A':6}, {'A':9}, {'A':0}, {'A':3}, {'A':4}]
df = pd.DataFrame(example)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
df
3
5
0
2
6
9
0
3
4
```

A new 'cluster' occurs after a 0 shows up in the df. I want to give each of these clusters an unique value, like this:

```
df
3    A
5    A
0    -
2    B
6    B
9    B
0    -
3    C
4    C
```

I have tried using enumerate and itertools but since I am new to Python I am struggling with the correct usage and syntax of these options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` and map to letters with `chr`:

```
m = df['A'].eq(0)
df['B'] = m.cumsum().add(65).map(chr).mask(m, '-')
df

   A  B
0  3  A
1  5  A
2  0  B
3  2  B
4  6  B
5  9  B
6  0  C
7  3  C
8  4  C
```

---

A NumPy solution can be written from this using `views`, and should be quite fast:

```
m = np.cumsum(df['A'].values == 0)
# thanks to @user3483203 for the neat trick! 
df['B'] = (m + 65).view('U2')
df

   A  B
0  3  A
1  5  A
2  0  B
3  2  B
4  6  B
5  9  B
6  0  C
7  3  C
8  4  C
```

From v0.22, you can also do this through pandas `Series.view`:

```
m = df['A'].eq(0)
df['B'] = (m.cumsum()+65).view('U2').mask(m, '-')
df

   A  B
0  3  A
1  5  A
2  0  -
3  2  B
4  6  B
5  9  B
6  0  -
7  3  C
8  4  C
```

Comment: Well this is pretty neat

Comment: @yatu Like the use of `np.where` as well :)

Comment: `(m.cumsum() + 65).view('U1').mask(m, '-')` should be faster than `map`

Comment: So I'm guessing this means letters begin at position 65?

Comment: @user3483203 Don't think that works with Series as-is, but view would be a good solution working with numpy

Comment: @yatu cumsum starts from zero, I then add 65 for ascii value uppercase 'A'.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html  I believe it's been included since `0.22.0`

Comment: Yes I mean in the ascii table :) Thx for clarifying was just checking now. Meant letters sorry

Comment: Problem here is that this continues with lowercase letters. Gussing OP is going with this option as there might be few groups? Definitely nicest approach to exactly meet OPs output though

Comment: @yatu Point... if there are many groups, best to go with a numeric labelling.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). I'm using numerical labeling here, which might be more appropiate in the case there are many groups:

```
import numpy as np

m = df.eq(0)
df['A'] = np.where(m, '-', m.cumsum())

   A
0  0
1  0
2  - 
3  1
4  1
5  1
6  - 
7  2
8  2
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC

```
import string
s=df.A.eq(0).cumsum()
d=dict(zip(s.unique(),string.ascii_uppercase[:s.max()+1]))
s.loc[df.A!=0].map(d).reindex(df.index,fill_value='-')
Out[360]: 
0    A
1    A
2    -
3    B
4    B
5    B
6    -
7    C
8    C
Name: A, dtype: object
```